# Android How to post own Bitmap on facebook wall

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

I am trying to take a photo and post it on my facebook wall. I've already taken the photo but I don't manage to post it with the Facebook sdk.

I've tried with Bundle :

```
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString (Facebook.TOKEN,facebook.getAccessToken());
parameters.putString ("message", "MessageOnWall");
parameters.putByteArray ("source", byteArray);
```

But I don't manage to create RequestListener to post in on the wall. 
I've been looking for an example but I haven't found it...
I'm new in android developement and I'm stuck on that problem.

Is there any other solution to make this?

Comment: Does your FB_API have the ability to post to the wall/have the correct permissions to post from that application for that username?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I finally solved my problem! I tried to post directly on my wall but I had to follow three steps to do it! I post an answer right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. To post a Bitmap on my wall, I do three steps :

1) I upload my Bitmap on facebook account (care, width and heigh of the photo must be under 720px) Don't forget to keep the ID of your photo!

2) I reach my photo with its ID and I extract from it the link

3) I finally post the link on my wall

You have to work with the [Graph API of facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) and you can test your code directly on your account [there](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=1614940318).
Don't forget the token to permit your app searching in your albums and publishing.

Hope is helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();

parameters.putString ("message", "MessageOnWall");
parameters.putByteArray ("picture", byteArray);
```

when putting byte array then use "picture" as key as shown in above lines. After that call request method as shown below.

```
    String response = mFacebook.request("me/photos",parameters,"POST");
```

By using this code your bitmap will be posted to wall.